# okhttp sent an error HTTP message, multiple request headers?

Tags: http, okhttp, wireshark

[image: Packet Capture Overview]

[image: Specific package]

As shown in the picture, when I make multiple requests quickly, I get strange packets through Wireshark, which are sent in the same TCP packet, does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Copy paste the text into the post.

Comment: I have searched the official github for a long time, but I don't see a similar issue, am I missing it?